# Keras: How to connect a CNN model with a decision tree

Tags: deep-learning, classification, keras, scikit-learn, decision-trees

I want to train a model to predict one's emotion from the physical signals. I have a physical signal and using it as input feature;

> ecg(Electrocardiography)

I want to use the CNN architecture to extract features from the data, and then use these extracted features to feed a classical **"Decision Tree Classifier"**. Below, you can see my CNN aproach without the decision tree;

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(15,60,padding='valid', activation='relu',input_shape=(18000,1), strides = 1,  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.1, l2=0.1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2,data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv1D(30, 60, padding='valid', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.1, l2=0.1), strides=1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(4,data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))
```

I want to edit this code so that, in the output layer there will be working **decision tree** instead of `model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))`. I have tried to save the outputs of the last convolutional layer like this;

```
output = model.layers[-6].output
```

And when I printed out the `output` variable, result was this;

> THE OUTPUT:  Tensor("conv1d_56/Relu:0", shape=(?, 8971, 30),
>   dtype=float32)

I guess, the `output` variable holds the extracted features. Now, how can I feed my **decision tree** classifier model  with this data which is stored in the `output` variable? Here is the decision tree from scikit learn;

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy')
dtc.fit()
```

How should I feed the `fit()` method? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the feature extraction to an intermediate model in keras. It could look something like this:

```
# Build a model for only the feature extraction layers
feature_extractor = Sequential()
feature_extractor.add(Conv1D(15,60,padding='valid', activation='relu',input_shape=(18000,1), strides = 1,  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.1, l2=0.1)))
feature_extractor.add(MaxPooling1D(2,data_format='channels_last'))
feature_extractor.add(Dropout(0.6))
feature_extractor.add(BatchNormalization())
feature_extractor.add(Conv1D(30, 60, padding='valid', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l1_l2(l1=0.1, l2=0.1), strides=1))

# Keep adding new layers for prediciton outside of feature extraction model
x = feature_extractor.output
x = MaxPooling1D(4,data_format='channels_last')(x)
x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
prediction_layer = Dense(3, activation = 'softmax')(x)

# Make a new model combining both
cnn_model=Model(inputs=feature_extractor.input, outputs=prediction_layer)
cnn_model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss=loss)
```

Then you train using the full `cnn_model` but you call predict only on your feature extraction model with `feature_extractor.predict(X)`. Then you can use the output of the prediction to train your decision tree like this:

```
# Train full network, both feature extractor and softmax part
cnn_model.fit(X, y_one_hot) # y needs to be one hot for keras

# Predict only the output of the feature extraction model
X_ext = feature_extractor.predict(X)

dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy')

# Train the decision tree on the extracted features
dtc.fit(X_ext, y) # y should be one-dimensional for sklearn
```